# yii2 : make SerialColumn a link

Tags: yii2

How to make the numbering result of the `SerialColumn` a link. Normally it generates number starting from 1. I want to make it a link. What property to use?

```
'columns' => [
    // ...
    [
        'class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn',
        // you may configure additional properties here
    ],
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't using the actual `SerialColumn` class.

That being said it should be fairly easy to do with a regular column. You can define a content callback that will receive all the necessary information to do this on its own:

```
'columns' => [
  // ...
  [
     'content' => function($model, $key, $index, $column) {
        $globalIndex = $index + 1;
        $pagination = $column->grid->dataProvider->getPagination();
        if ($pagination !== false) {
           $globalIndex = $pagination->getOffset() + $index + 1;
        }
        return \yii\helpers\Html::a($globalIndex, ['/route/action', 'id' => $globalIndex]);
     } 
  ],
  //...
]
```

**Note:** I haven't tested this so might not fully work out of the box.